# Trigger validation error in related model

Tags: php, validation, yii

I have a model in Yii that contains an array of another model type. I am then trying to validate that no duplicate emails are filled out in a form, where you can fill out for n number of persons at the same time.

My current approach is to trigger a custom validation of the "outer" model that holds all the entrants, however, that model is not accessible in the view, only the array of entrants is, and if I then trigger the error on the "outer" model, it will not be displayed to the user. Therefore I would like to trigger it for the first entrant that violates the rule, but how do I go about doing that?

My code that attempts this, looks like this so far:

```php
/*
 * Custom validation rule to hinder the same e-mail being used twice.
 */
public function noRepeatingEmails($attribute, $params)
{
  if (!isset($attribute)) return;

  $emails = array();
  foreach($this->$attribute as $user)
  {
    if (isset($user) && strlen(trim($user->email)) != 0)
    {
      $emailToAdd = strtolower(trim($user->email));
      if (in_array($emailToAdd, $emails))
      {
        $this->addError($user, '<my error message>');
        return;
      }
      else
      {
        $emails[] = $emailToAdd;
      }
    }      
  }
}
```

This only results in a code 500 error though:

```
Illegal offset type
```

I presume that is because it is looking for the property "user" in my model, rather than adding an error to "$user" object.

How do I best accomplish this?

*I have a .NET background, so I am probably doing loads wrong here however.*

Comment: Check  yii `unique` validation rule. `array('email', 'unique', 'message'=>'{attribute} already exist.')`

Comment: @harmed: I am not trying to validate against a database model, but to validate the current model before saving. A user can register multiple entrants at once, with each their own e-mail, and this is what I am trying to validate, and show validation error messages for.

Comment: "Before saving" was not entirely correct. It is before saving the data to the users session and proceed to the next step. Saving to db happens at a later step.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly from your comment, you want to **validate your model before saving it**. For this purpose, CActiveRecord provides [`beforeSave()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#beforeSave-detail) method. You need to put this method inside your model:

```
protected function beforeSave()
    {
        if(parent::beforeSave())
        {
            if(/* Your validation goes here*/)
                return true;
            else
                return false
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

When the result of this method is `true`, `save()` method will be called. Otherwise `save()` method won't be called and therefore no record will be saved into your database.

Comment: I already have db constraints in place to prevent it from happening, however I would like to inform the user in an earlier step that their input is invalid. The current step only saves the data to the session.